# IIS Server hanging at 350 requests per minute

Tags: iis, .net-4.0, sql-server-express

I have a website that continuously hangs at 350 - 380 page requests per minute. It is a c# .NET 4 website running on a 2008 R2 server running iis 7 and SQL Server Express.  It ultilises EF, version that came with .NET 4.  I have compiled most of the queries.

I generally have to restart IIS to to get it serving again.

The server is a 4mghz 8 core 1 CPU server with 32 Gigs of RAM.

I have

- increased the maxconcurrentpercpu to 200 or 300
- increased the queue length in iis 10 000
- changed the max pool size in iss to 300
- increased the timeouts, but then reduced them to ensure they do not block further requests
- increased the threads per processor Limit in IIS to 100

but it is still hanging at about 350 page requests (230 - 230 active uses).  Funny enough this seems to be hard limit of sorts.

(I should set the application timeout to default and selectively increase certain pages timeouts?)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look performance counters, like Requests Per Second and Current Requests. Try to catch Current Requests during one of these hangs and see if they trend up and just keep going, that'll reveal that requests are blocking on something and just keep piling up will the app pool breaks.

Also, download [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40336) and set it up to watch your app pool and collect a dump that will show where things are breaking. Relatively easy to figure out how to use it.

Also, SqlServer express has it's own limitation of CPU/memory, may be the load you're putting on it is too much.

This doesn't sound like an IIS issue though.